# Problem in debugging django project using VS code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have a problem while debugging a django project using VS code, the problem that nothing happened when I click to debug button, I can launch my script just by tapping in terminal `python manage.py runserver`.

Here is my launch.json file, and note please that I tried a lot of examples, and still the same problem:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Django",
            "python": "C:/Users/msekmani/Desktop/dashboard_project/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/Users/msekmani/Desktop/dashboard_project/IPv2/src/manage.py",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "args": ["runserver"],
           "django": true,
           "justMyCode": true,
        },
    ]
}
```

I am using python version 3.6 and for the OS is Windows.

Note please that I also tried to creat a Python debug and also it's not working also, and here is my launch.json script:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Instead of using django debugger, try creating a python file debug, and then give it some arguments.

Comment: If you run as the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oujc4.png), can it work well?

Comment: I have tried creating a python debug and it's not working also, I forget to mention this in the problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to solve this problem by upgrade the python version to 3.7, I don't have any idea about the problem happened in version 3.6, by the way, the upgrade python version is the solution.